Resuming a conversation using the Semantic Kernel and the OpenAIAssistantAgent C#
What I do now is creating the OpenAIAssistantAgent, creating a thread and storing the thread id, adding the chat messages to the agent using the thread id, invoking the agent using the thread id and displaying the results.
What would I need to do to resume the a conversation started with the OpenAIAssistantAgent at a later stage, for example when my agent is restarted?

Managed to achieve this by saving the conversation messages and pass these as input when recreating the conversation thread.
